# postgres, update values using another table that describes changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to update a database table using another table that describes the changes to be made?  For example, here is the table that needs to be updated:

```
| number | cola | colb |
|--------|------|------|
| a1     | 7    | aaa  |
| a2     | 5    | bbb  |
| b1     | 4    | ccc  |
| b2     | 2    | ddd  |
| c1     | 5    | eee  |
| c2     | 6    | fff  |
```

and here is the other table describing the required updates:

```
| number | colname | old_value | new_value |
|--------|---------|-----------|-----------|
| a1     | cola    | 7         | 100       |
| a2     | cola    | 5         | 1000      |
| a2     | colb    | bbb       | BBB       |
```

To see my attempt, here is this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/01e1a).  Is there a straightforward way to do this?  Or am I going to have too many type casting issues?

Answer (score 1):

You need an update statement for each column.

```sql
UPDATE data
   SET COLB = c.new_value
  FROM ( SELECT number, old_value, new_value
           FROM changelist
          WHERE field_name = 'COLB'
       ) c
 WHERE data.number = c.number
   AND data.COLB = c.old_value;
```

```sql
UPDATE data
   SET COLC = c.new_value
  FROM ( SELECT number, old_value, new_value
           FROM changelist
          WHERE field_name = 'COLC'
       ) c
 WHERE data.number = c.number
   AND data.COLC = c.old_value;
```

See it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/01e1a/4).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest aggregating the changes and then `join`ing:

```
update toupdate
     set cola = coalesce(cl.cola, toupdate.cola),
         colb = coalesce(cl.colb, toupdate.colb)
     from (select max(case when colname = 'cola' then newvalue end) as cola,
                  max(case when colname = 'colb' then newvalue end) as colb
                  . . . 
           from changelist cl
           group by number
          ) cl
     where cl.number = toupdate.number;
```

I recommend this over an approach that updates each column separately, because this updates a single row only once.

EDIT:

Handling `NULL` values as a *new* value requires knowing which are updated.  One method is a flag:

```
update toupdate
     set cola = (case when cl.has_cola then toupdate.cola else cl.cola end),
         colb = (case when cl.has_colb then toupdate.colb else cl.colb end),
         . . . 
     from (select max(new_value) filter (where colname = 'cola') as cola,
                  max(new_value) filter (where colname = 'colb') as colb,
                  . . . ,
                  bool_or(colname = 'cola') as has_cola,
                  bool_or(colname = 'colb') as has_colb,
                  . . . 
           from changelist cl
           group by number
          ) cl
     where cl.number = toupdate.number;
```

Comment: @bill_e . . . If the new value can be `NULL`, you should be clear in the question.  There are no examples of `NULL` values in the question.  (This answer can be tweaked to handle that situation.)

Comment: Great answer and thanks for pointing that out @Andreas, but yes, NULL is a possibility.